# chrome extension about browser action

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to alert some message when i click the broweraction icon,there is my code,but it doesn't work,can some one help me? thanks!!

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "brower_action":{ "default_icon":"test.png"},
  "background_page":"background.html",
  "permissions":["tabs","http://*/*","https://*/"]
}
```

**script.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  null, {code:"alert('test')"});
});
```

**background.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a * missing in your manifest permissions https://*/  .  Maybe its only the stackoverflow editor that missed it.

Answer (score 1):

All you need in script.js is:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  alert('test');
});
```

Comment: Excuse me,I have try it, but still not work!! Is there other problem in my code? Thanks your help!

Comment: In `background.html` you specify `background.js` but you label the script as `script.js`. Make sure they are the same.